# Develop visual editor tool on top of eclipse platform

Tags: java, architecture, eclipse-plugin

All UI scenes of our application declared in json files and then gets rendered at runtime by special engine. Too many time spends on writing json by hands. Will be very convenient to implement some visual tool for creating UI scenes in a drag-and-drop manner (e.g. creating swing application with eclipse windowbuilder plugin, or creating birt xml reports with birt-designer eclipse plugin). Is there any best practices, methodologies, frameworks, docs, etc to start project in a right way? Thnx in advance.

Comment: I'm not sure this is easiest. There are facilities in Eclipse (for example BIRT or GEF) but some might find it a mess. Personally I've taken the inverse direction and gone full web now that websockets, svg, canvas, and efficient js engines make it possible.

Comment: thnx for reply. I see SWT designer implemented with GEF, so maybe this is what I am looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd look at the source of [Eclispe SWT designer](http://sourceforge.net/projects/eclipsedesigner/).